# How to make Chinese characters display properly on Chromium

Tags: debian, fonts

When I use Iceweasel (Debian version of Firefox), I can see Chinese characters found on [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_characters#Comparisons_of_traditional_Chinese.2C_simplified_Chinese.2C_and_Japanese), but not when using Chromium. I instead see rectangles. This is on Debian 7 (Wheezy).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firefox's rendering engine will substitute glyphs from other installed fonts (if it can find one with the required glyph) instead of displaying broken glyphs. Chromium will stick to the specified font(s) instead, and will display a "missing glyph" character if the glyph is not found.

For Chromium and possibly other programs, you need to install Chinese fonts. I usually use arphic fonts: [fonts-arphic-ukai](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/fonts-arphic-ukai), [fonts-arphic-uming](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/fonts-arphic-uming).

Comment: wots the difference between those 2... Kaiti vs. Mingti

Comment: I just install both. Can't read anyway :P

Comment: "Firefox ships with some fonts of its own". Could you provide one reference for this statement? I am experience this problem OP posted, and the final conclusion lies on [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=229051). After removing Droid font, installed in Linux by default, Firefox can't display Chinese properly, either, so I believe that Firefox doesn't have builtin fonts.

Comment: @AlbertNetymk back then I didn't really know certain things. I have updated the answer with my current understandings :)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I found this [bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31232) firstly, when I google this issue. Then, I realized that it has been merged into [this](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=229051). I kind of believe that the underlying reason is that chromium doesn't use `lang` properly, as discussed in the bug report.

Comment: There's a description of different font styles at [jiromaiya.wordpress.com](http://jiromaiya.wordpress.com/2013/01/04/fundamentals-of-chinese-typography-1-fonts-styles-typefaces-songti-fangsongti-mingti-heiti-kaiti/), @Tshepang. Kaiti looks more like calligraphy, and Mingti looks like printing.

Answer (score 23):

This page has specific information for installing font packages on Debian.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Multilingual_support_(East_Asian)

- Chinese (both Simplified & Traditional)

  - Serif: `fonts-arphic-ukai`
  - Sans-serif: `fonts-arphic-uming`
- Japanese

  - Serif: `fonts-ipafont-mincho`
  - Sans-serif: `fonts-ipafont-gothic`
- Korean

  - All: `fonts-unfonts-core`

After installing these font packages, try this page as a test:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_unification#Examples_of_language_dependent_characters

For me on Debian/Linux, Chrome refuses to recognize the embedded language meta tags, but Firefox/Iceweasel can handle.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 11):

**Debian-based GNU/Linux**

In order to display Chinese, Japanese and/or Korean characters, you must install some font packages:

- Chinese: `fonts-arphic-ukai` (Serif), `fonts-arphic-uming` (Sans serif)
- Japanese: `fonts-ipafont-mincho` (Serif), `fonts-ipafont-gothic` (Sans serif)
- Korean: `fonts-unfonts-core` (Serif + Sans serif)

There are some alternative packages for some languages, but the ones listed above do work. To install all the fonts listed above in Debian, Ubuntu, and other variants:

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-arphic-ukai fonts-arphic-uming fonts-ipafont-mincho fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-unfonts-core
```

**Arch Linux**

For a large collection of fonts which comprehensively support Simplified Chinese, Traditional Chinese, Japanese, and Korean, with a consistent design and look, install the following package:

```
pacman -S adobe-source-han-sans-otc-fonts
```

**Fedora Linux**

```
yum install fonts-japanese fonts-chinese fonts-korean
```

**Gentoo Linux**

Enabling the *cjk* (Chinese, Japanese, Korean) use flag improves East Asian support in some packages, but is not essential.

```
emerge arphicfonts baekmuk-fonts kochi-substitute
```

Those packages are:

- [arphicfonts](http://packages.gentoo.org/package/media-fonts/arphicfonts) (han)
- [baekmuk-fonts](http://packages.gentoo.org/package/media-fonts/baekmuk-fonts) (hangul)
- [kochi-substitute](http://packages.gentoo.org/package/media-fonts/kochi-substitute) (hiragana/katakana).

**Mageia v6**

```
urpmi fonts-ttf-japanese fonts-ttf-chinese fonts-ttf-korean
```

**Mageia v7**

```
dnf install fonts-ttf-japanese fonts-ttf-chinese fonts-ttf-korean
```

**FreeBSD**

*CJK* fonts can be installed on FreeBSD using [freebsd ports collection](http://www.freebsd.org/ports/)

```
cd /usr/ports/x11-fonts/cyberbit-ttfonts && make install clean
cd /usr/ports/japanese/font-kochi && make install clean
```

or by installing precompiled packages:

```
pkg install ja-font-kochi
```

**NetBSD**

On NetBSD and other systems using *pkgsrc*, one can install *CJK* fonts with the following commands:

```
 cd /usr/pkgsrc/fonts/kochi-ttf && make install clean
 cd /usr/pkgsrc/fonts/cyberbit-ttf && make install clean
```

**Other UNIX Distributions**

Download the appropriate .ttf file (for example, kochi-gothic-subst.ttf) and copy it to your system's TrueType font directory (for example, `/usr/lib/X11/fonts/TTF/`). For example, (for `Dejavu fonts`):

```
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/dejavu/dejavu/2.35/dejavu-fonts-ttf-2.35.tar.bz2
tar -xjvf dejavu-fonts-ttf-2.33.tar.bz2
cp ./dejavu-fonts-ttf-2.33/ttf/* /usr/lib/X11/fonts/TTF
```

Or get the link to the current version [here](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/index.php?title=Download), then run (as root) the following then X if it is in use, and the new font should be installed:

```
fc-cache /usr/lib/X11/fonts/TTF/
```

**GNOME**

GNOME supports East Asian characters natively. You may need to install appropriate fonts.

**KDE 5**

KDE 5 supports East Asian characters natively. You may need to install appropriate fonts.

**KDE 4**

KDE supports East Asian characters natively. You may need to install the following packages:

- Simplified Chinese: `kde-l10n-zhcn`
- Traditional Chinese: `kde-l10n-zhtw`
- Japanese: `kde-l10n-ja`
- Korean: `kde-l10n-ko`

If this does not help, or works partially, but some characters are still missing, you may need to run qtconfig, and add a comprehensive unicode font to your chosen browser font's substitutions.

**Note**

Chrome/Chromium need to be restarted after installing the needed packages

**Sources and tests**

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Multilingual_support_(East_Asian))

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If you using Linux (Like Debian/Ubuntu), 3 steps as Following:
Step 1: install Asia font;

```
$ sudo apt-get install fonts-arphic-ukai fonts-arphic-uming fonts-ipafont-mincho fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-unfonts-core
```

Step 2: Using it in Python

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
font = {'family': 'AR PL UKai CN',
                     'weight': 'bold',
                     'size': '10'}
plt.rc('font', **font)
plt.rc('axes', unicode_minus=False)
time_points = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])  
temperature_rates = np.array([2, 3, 1, -2, 4])  
curvature = np.gradient(temperature_rates, time_points, edge_order=2)
inflection_points = time_points[np.where(curvature == 0)]
print(inflection_points)
plt.plot(time_points, temperature_rates, label='温度变化率曲线')
plt.scatter(inflection_points, np.zeros_like(inflection_points), color='red', label='拐点')
plt.xlabel('时间')
plt.ylabel('温度变化率')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Step 3(Optional): You can print all fonts like this:

```
print(matplotlib.matplotlib_fname())
a=sorted([f.name for f in matplotlib.font_manager.fontManager.ttflist])  
  
for i in a:  
    print(i)
```

[image]